# nginx client certificate location block

Tags: nginx, authentication, certificate

How can I use client certificate authentication with nginx for a folder?
The `ssl_client_certificate` directive isn't allowed in `location` blocks.
Example: I want my website `me.tld` to be reachable by all clients and everything below `me.tld/secure/` only by authenticated clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not in a position to try this myself but you could try the following

You will need `ssl_verify_client optional;` to go along side `ssl_client_certificate` and then use the following location block

```
location /secure {
    error_page 418 = @other;
    recursive_error_pages on;
    if ($ssl_client_verify = SUCCESS) {
    return 418
    }

location @other {
    #Secure Config goes here
    }
```

The client certificate will be checked but not enforced for all locations. When someone tries the `/secure` directory nginx will then check to see if `$ssl_client_verify` was successful at the `server` level. If it was it will `return` error `418` which we told nginx to deal with in the `@other` location.